# Does ZXing project checks any of elements in ISO 18004 in section Annex K?

Tags: java, zxing

When reading about QR standard ISO 18004, in section Annex K (page 91), it analyzes for the parameters of Decode, Symbol Contrast, “Print” Growth, Axial Nonuniformity, and Unused Error Correction, then comes up with a Symbol Grade. Anyone know if ZXing library checks for any of these five elements?

Comment: Don't know but you could probably check the source and find out - http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/checkout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, these are not part of decoding, but part of a print verification process. It is not implemented in the project.

Comment: there is a formula e + 2t <= d - p in the ISO. is there any way to get the value of e and t.